# Is there a way to print patterns to new files using awk or python?

Tags: python, awk

So I have a .txt file with 6 columns (there is no header in the real file) that looks like:

```
|$1 | $2 | $3 | $4 | $5 | Flag |
|:--:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | -1 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 0 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 1 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 2 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | -1 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 0|
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 1 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 2 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | -1 |
|Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 | Foo5 | 0|
etc
```

The file has varying amounts of lines between each iteration of -1 and 2 but the 2 flag is always followed by a -1. Is there a way I can print each one of these patterns to seperate files?

If you know of any ways to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "each one of these patterns"?  Are you saying that each "set" of lines should start with a -1 and ends with a 2?  How would you generate the file names?  Are the columns tab separated, comma separated, what?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, this is very easy to do with a small script of python. Not sure how to do it with an awk script but it may be possible. Is this a real world problem or homework assignment or test? If its the latter, you really should make a go at writing a solution and then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: You can use awk's `> filename` operator to print to a file. Whenever you get a line with flag = -1, you update the filename variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) remove the header and any other lines from your sample input that are not present in your real data, b) verify that there may or may not be blanks around all of the `|`s (e.g. `| 0 |` vs `| 0|`, and c) add the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably all you need:

```
awk -F' *[|] *' '$(NF-1) == -1{close(out); out="out"(++c)} {print > out}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to generate the names:

```
filenum = 0
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    final = line.strip().split()[-1]
    if final == '-1':
        fout = open('file%04d.txt'%filenum, 'w')
        filenum += 1
    fout.write( line )
```